# In Assembly Language I am using 16 bits register,How I print 6 in this code?

Tags: arrays, assembly

```
.data

num dw 2,4,6,8,10

.code

main proc

mov eax,0

mov si,2

mov ax,num[si*2]
```

I want to print the array element 6 but error is invalid use of register. how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess this is 16-bit 80x86 assembly. I can't guess which assembler it is (it's not GAS/AT&T and probably not NASM/YASM/FASM, and possibly MASM or TASM). Without knowing which assembler I can't know the syntax it expects.

However, for 16-bit addressing on 80x86 there is no way to encode that instruction (assuming it's not a syntax error to begin with). Alternatives include:

a) do `add si,si` and then (depending on which assembler) either `mov ax,[num+si]` or `mov ax,num[si]`.

b) do `mov bx,si` and then (depending on which assembler) either `mov ax,[num+bx+si]` or `mov ax,num[bx+si]`.

c) do `mov si,2*2` and then (depending on which assembler) either `mov ax,[num+si]` or `mov ax,num[si]`.

d) if it's 16-bit code running on a 32-bit CPU; do `mov esi,2` and then (depending on which assembler) either `mov ax,[num+esi*2]` or `mov ax,num[esi*2]`.

e) (depending on which assembler) either `mov ax,[num+2*2]` or I have no idea what (maybe `mov ax,(num+2*2)[]`?).

Comment: I am using MASM in VS 2013 by using Irvine32 Libraries. I am new in Assembly but I got your point. Thanks again my problem solved.